# Jupyter session cannot open csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

Cannot determine why Jupyter cannot load my csv file..
The code I have in Jupyter cell is pretty simple

```
    import pandas as pd 
    df = pd.read_csv(r"purchases.csv")
```

### getting the error below

CParserError                         [image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-139a6a5372f2> in <module>()
      3 
      4 
----> 5 df = pd.read_csv(r"purchases.csv")
      6 df
      7
```

Name of Notebook is Pandas Tet
[image: s]

In my directory, I can see the csv file- purchases.csv
Plz advise - have spent a lot of time and I cannot figure it out.

I am taking coursera course and downloaded their notes. I can read mpg.csv and their other files. Do I have to do anything special on files which I create. I have searched online and cannot determine a solution. Thx in advance

Comment: why use raw string ?

Comment: For example, this article may be helpful. [How to specify file path in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58020062/9014308)

Comment: Hi kunif.. tried that link and no success

Comment: Hi Philip.. Have tried using c:\\....\\purchases.csv, c:\purchases.csv, in single quotes ,double quotes and no success

Comment: Hello. the r string use if you use path with backslash for example this path `c:\purchases.csv` but if your notebook file is in the same folder with the `purchases.csv` file, then you just need the filename instead of the full path. Try `df = pd.read_csv('purchases.csv')`

Comment: Verify if the file is indeed there: `import os`, then `dir_content = os.listdir('.')` and check if your file is listed: `'purchases.csv' in dir_content`. Does it return `True`? If so, can you open and read the file: `with open('purchases.csv', 'r') as fp: file_contents = fp.read()`?

Comment: He deeenes..  can see purchases.csv if I do os.listdir.. I did your open cmd and get below error..  I can open purchases.csv from MS-DOS prompt (not just from Jupyter)                                                                                      
---------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ad5e6fd14949> in <module>()
     18     print("Present")
     19 with open('purchases.csv', 'r') as fp:
---> 20     file_contents = fp.read

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 14: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

The following should work since the csv file is in the same folder as the ipynb file.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("purchases.csv")
```